# sql: find the largest number in cube

Tags: sql-server, ssas, cube, olap-cube

I am facing a SQL OLAP cube issue where I am not getting the output I want. I'm currently getting 0 row when I execute the code.

the question: for each town, find the product id offered in the largest quantity.

Below is my code:

```
SELECT [supplier town], [product id], [quantity]
FROM my_cube
WHERE "supplier town" is not null
AND "supplier name" is not null
GROUP BY [supplier town], [product id], [quantity]
HAVING [quantity] >= ALL(
   SELECT [quantity]
   FROM my_cube)
```

Here is the output without the second/ bottom part of my code = GROUP BY, HAVING.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql` tag for SQL-Server questions.

Answer (score 0):

This works, see results below.
Please note data for Madison/Gas is only 200000,
and Stevens Point has two products with same quantity, and Wausau has been added.

```
SELECT [supplier town], [product id], [quantity]
FROM my_cube aa
WHERE "supplier town" is not null
--AND "supplier name" is not null
GROUP BY [supplier town], [product id], [quantity]
HAVING [quantity] >= ALL(
   SELECT [quantity]
   FROM my_cube bb where aa.[supplier town] = bb.[supplier town])

supplier town   product id  quantity
Chicago         Computer    1010
Madison         Gas         200000
Springfield     Computer    100
Stevens Point   Airplane    110000
Stevens Point   Computer    110000
Wausau          Boat        200100
```

Answer (score 0):

A much cleaner approach to this problem is obtained by using the SQL ranking functions.  For instance...

```
drop table if exists #data;

create table #data(
    city nvarchar(100) ,
    product nvarchar(100) ,
    quantity int
);

insert  #data
values  ('Chicago', 'Airplane', 1000) ,
        ('Chicago', 'Boat', 10) ,
        ('Chicago', 'Computer', 1010) ,
        ('Stevens Point', 'Computer', 100) ,
        ('Stevens Point', 'Airplane', 110000) ,
        ('Stevens Point', 'Computer', 110000)
;


select  city ,
        product ,
        quantity ,
        row_number() over (partition by city order by quantity desc, product desc) as [order]
from    #data
```

If you want to select just the top one for each city, the final query is a little more complicated but not bad ...

```
select  *
from    (
    select  city ,
            product ,
            quantity ,
            row_number() over (partition by city order by quantity desc, product desc) as [order]
    from    #data
) x
where   x.[order] = 1
```

... or if you want to be fancy and use CTE's ...

```
with
    x as (
        select  city ,
                product ,
                quantity ,
                row_number() over (partition by city order by quantity desc, product desc) as [order]
        from    #data
    )
select * from x where [order] = 1
```